# The use of " level"

Tags: word-usage

I would like to ask if I use the word "level" correctly in the following sentences.

> A good education has many benefits in individual **level** and society
>   **level**.

I imagine there is a relation between individual and society and it is drawn in levels figuratively because individuals,are at bottom level, create the society.

Another example:

> Having a healthy diet brings many benefits into our lives in physical 
>   and psychological **level**.

Comment: Sure, the usages are idiomatic (sidenote: it's typically not necessary to argue the *logic* of a construction to determine its *linguistic* validity; it is sufficient to show people, broadly, *use* it).

Comment: For *level,* British English would normally use *at:* "at the individual level and societal level; at the physical and psychological level."

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Likewise AmEng.  Reading "in individual level" feels very awkward and I wonder if it is even grammatically correct.  Whereas "at the individual level" is fine.

Comment: @AndrewLeach _At_ probably is the more commonly accepted vernacular here though I believe a strong case could be made for the word _on_  -- "_on both individual and societal levels._"

Comment: I also support using *on*: *on an individual level and a societ**al** level*.   No problem with *at*, though.

Comment: This may help to see which preposition is used more https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+societal+level%2Cat+individual+level%2Con+individual+level%2Cat+societal+level%2Cat+psychological+level%2Con+psychological+level&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20societal%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20individual%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20individual%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20societal%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20psychological%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20psychological%20level%3B%2Cc0